# can * be substituted for a value in mysql WHERE

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to filter my results using a series of dropdown boxes which are populated from other tables within the database, except for a primary option which is returned from the form as `*`

Currently the form submits the data as expected, but no results are returned.  I suspect it is because the query is searching for `*` in the respective columns.

So the question is, can an asterisk be used as a wildcard in a WHERE statement? 
And if not, how would I go about this instead?

offending code is included, i understand that using a `$variable` in a query is bad practice, but at this stage i'm searching for a functional solution, rather than production code.

cheers.

```
echo "  <form method=\"post\" action=\"$self\">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>REGISTER</th>
                    <th>LOCATION</th>
                    <th>TYPE</th>
                    <th>CAPACITY</th>
                    <th>LENGTH</th>
                    <th>QTY</th>
                    <th>SERIAL#</th>
                    <th>CERT#</th>
                    <th>LAST INSPECTION</th>
                    <th>BY</th>
                    <th>DATE IN</th>
                    <th>DATE OUT</th>
                    <th>STATUS</th>
                    <th>NOTES</th>
                </tr>";
                ?>

       <!-- START OF FILTER ROW -->
        <tr>
            <td></td>
          <td>  <select name="register" id="register">
                <option value="*">---</option>
                <?php 
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM valid_registers";
                    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row)
                    {
                      echo "<option value\"" . $row['register'] . "\">" . $row['register'] . "</option>";
                    }
                ?>              
              </select></td>
          <td>  <select name="location" id="location">
                <option value="*">---</option>
                <?php 
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM valid_locations";
                    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row)
                    {
                      echo "<option value\"" . $row['location'] . "\">" . $row['location'] . "</option>";
                    }
                ?>
              </select></td>
          <td>  <select name="type" id="type">
                <option value="*">---</option>
                <?php 
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM valid_types";
                    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row)
                    {
                      echo "<option value\"" . $row['type'] . "\">" . $row['type'] . "</option>";
                    }
                ?>              
                </select>      </td>
          <td><input type="radio" name="capacity" id="cap_asc" value="cap_asc">
            &lt; 
            <input type="radio" name="capacity" id="cap_dec" value="cap_dec">
            &gt;</td>
          <td><input type="radio" name="length" id="length_asc" value="length_asc">
            &lt;
            <input type="radio" name="length" id="length_des" value="length_des">
            &gt;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td><input type="radio" name="lastinsp" id="lastinsp_asc" value="lastinsp_asc">
        &lt;
        <input type="radio" name="lastinsp" id="lastinsp_dec" value="lastinsp_dec">
        &gt;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td><input type="radio" name="datein" id="datein_asc" value="datein_asc">
        &lt;
        <input type="radio" name="datein" id="datein_dec" value="datein_dec">
        &gt;</td>
              <td><input type="radio" name="dateout" id="dateout_asc" value="dateout_asc">
        &lt;
        <input type="radio" name="dateout" id="dateout_dec" value="dateout_dec">
        &gt;</td>
          <td>  <select name="status" id="status">
                <option value="*">---</option>
                <?php 
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM valid_status";
                    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row)
                    {
                      echo "<option value\"" . $row['status'] . "\">" . $row['status'] . "</option>";
                    }
                ?>
                </select>      </td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td><input type="submit" name="submit_filter" id="submit_filter" value="Filter"></td>
        </tr>
<!--END OF FILTER ROW -->

<?
//get data from the db
if(isset($_POST['submit_filter'])) { 

    //fetch filter options
    $register = $_POST['register'];
    $location = $_POST['location'];
    $type = $_POST['type'];
    $status = $_POST['status'];

    //prepare and execute the query
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE register=$reigster AND location=$location AND type=$type AND status=$status ";

}

else { $sql = "SELECT * FROM register"; }


    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row)
        {
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['register'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['location'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['type'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['capacity'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['length'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['qty'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['serial'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['cert'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['lastinsp'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['inspby'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['datein'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['dateout'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['notes'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td><a href='" . $self . "?edit=" . $row['id'] . "'>Edit</a></td>";
          //echo "<td><input type=\"submit\" name=\"edit\" id=\"edit\" value=\"Edit\" /></td>";
          echo "<td><a href='" . $self . "?delete=" . $row['id'] . "'>Delete</a></td>";
          //echo "<td><input type=\"submit\" name=\"delete\" id=\"delete\" value=\"Delete\" /></td>";
          echo "</tr>";
        }
echo "</table></form>";
}
```

Comment: your sql query is vulnerable to sql injection

Answer (score 0):

No, the `*` is really only valid in the columns you *select,* not in the where clause.

The usual way to do this is to catch the `*` from the form and use that to modify the actual SQL statement by removing that part of the `where` clause altogether, something like (pseudo-code):

```
if param['userid'] == '*':
    query = 'select name from users'
else:
    query = 'select name from users where id = ?'
```

Although I *have* seen cases where parameterised queries needed a consistent number of parameters regardless of wild-carding (in some BIRT reports I've looked at where the query is modified dynamically but the parameter count is harder to change), so you would get something like:

```
if param['userid'] == '*':
    query = 'select name from users where (id = ? or 1 = 1)'
else:
    query = 'select name from users where id = ?'
```

That's a bit of a kludge but it's sometimes used to ease the developers workload. I'd rather do it the first way where possible.

---

To do that for *multiple* conditions, you can do something like:

```
joiner = " where "
query = "select something from mytable"
if param['userid'] != '*':
    query = query + joiner + "user_id = '" + param['id'] + "'"
    joiner = " and "
if param['age'] != '*':
    query = query + joiner + "user_age = " + param['age']
    joiner = " and "
if param['gender'] != '*':
    query = query + joiner + "user_sex = '" + param['gender'] + "'"
    joiner = " and "
```

keeping in mind that, unless you have already sanitised your `param[]` array values, you risk SQL injection attacks). I leave out the solution for that since it's irrelevant to the question at hand.

Comment: might this be as simple as setting the value of the `$var` to an empty string if the form returns `*` or could i just set the value of the input in the form to an emptry string?

Comment: @Zach, if you use the empty string, it's only going to give you rows that match an empty string. That's just as bad as rows which match the literal `*`. You need to disable the effect of the `where` clause entirely for wild-carding.

Comment: if I am reading correctly, your example above would only work if I was to filter by only ONE of my given dropdown boxes... could you suggest something that might work if I wanted to filter using multiple dropdowns?

Comment: @Zach, yes, you do the same thing to the _other_ parts of the where clause. I'll add some other text to the answer.